# moving UILabels on screen using NSMutablearray

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a button linked to a iboutlet. When the button is clicked (*buttonlabel), a label is generated. the label can be moved on the screen in any position. if i click the button again, another label is generated, but i can't move the first one any more. I searched on the internet, and found I have to use a NSMutablearray, but this does not seem to work:

in.m

```
-(IBAction)button3Pressed:(id)sender{

  self.buttonBrush.selected = NO;
self.buttonBrush.highlighted = NO;
self.buttonlabel.selected = YES;
self.buttonlabel.highlighted = YES;
self.buttontextbox.selected = NO;
self.buttontextbox.highlighted = NO;


CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake( 400, 100, 100, 30);

label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
[label1 setText: @"Untitled"];
[label1 setTextColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
[self.view addSubview:label1];
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

 if (array == nil) array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [array addObject:label1];

}
```

then

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

//label1

if (buttonlabel.selected == YES){

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];


    UIView *touchedView = [touch view];

    if ([array containsObject:touchedView]){

        touchedView.center = location;  
    }
}

 }
```

in .h I added:

```
 IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    NSMutableArray *array;
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You have a single '=' instead of '==' in the last if statement. Also, don't think it makes much sense to decorate your array with IBOOutlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  Use this instead to test all of the label's in the array:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    for (UILabel *label in array) {
        CGPoint localLocation = [label convertPoint:location fromView:self.view];
        if ([label pointInside:localLocation withEvent:nil]) {
            label.center = location;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does not seem to be working. there are no errors, but what do you mean by "move the line...so that it is after". do I need to place it after the alloc??

Comment: That would work, but i would put it after I finish configuring the label.  (after ` label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`)

Comment: please help!! does not work at all, the label just doesn't move

Comment: my guess is that the array is never created in the first place.   Just before the '[array addObject...' line put: 'if (array == nil) array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];'

Comment: obviously I uploaded just the part related to this, because I have other codes to move taxfileds and UIImages, but all have this problem